# Elegant way to skip and take items from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a List of 10 items. The idea is to take the first 5 for the left column and the last 5 for the right column.

I then insert the left 5 into each individual div (as each single div has a corresponding number) and the same for the right column.

**Example HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="leftOne">@leftInfoOne </div>
        <div class="leftTwo">@leftInfoTwo </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="rightOne">@rightInfoOne </div>
        <div class="rightTwo">@rightInfoTwo </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far i have done something as below in my Razor view

```cs
var allleftItems = ctx.Customers.Take(5);
var allRightItems = ctx.Customers.Skip(Math.Max(0, ctx.Customers.Count() - 2));
```

Then under each left/right div i have declared single items as below

```
var leftInfoOne = allleftItems.Element(0)
var leftInfoTwo = allleftItems.Element(1)
```

And the same for the right div except swapping the names and collection name.

Is there a more elegant way for me to achieve this rather than creating a variable to hold each element?
I thought about a `foreach` but then each div would be different i.e. `leftOne` and `leftTwo` would need the appropriate element for that div?

Comment: _"I have a List of 10 items."_ -  is the size guaranteed? Or you need to split list in 2 no matter what is the size?

Comment: Yes its guaranteed

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but (if you're using .NET Core 3.1 or later) you can obtain `allRightItems` like so: `var allRightItems = ctx.Customers.Skip(5).TakeLast(5);`

Comment: But (since you said you the list is guaranteed to be 10 items) you can just do `var allRightItems = ctx.Customers.TakeLast(5);`

Comment: Then based on description you can do `Skip(5).Take(5)` or just `TakeLast(5)` .

Comment: When you say `list` do you really mean it's a `List<T>` of size 10? Because then you could just use `Customers[0]`, `Customers[1]` etc without using Linq at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loops/cycles in your markup. If you want to keep the number as words in styles you can do something like the following:

```cs
// somewhere in code
string[] nums = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" }; // TODO: move to static readonly collection
var lefts = allleftItems.Take(5);
var rights = allleftItems.Skip(5).Take(5);
```

Markup:

```
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left">
        @foreach (var curr in lefts.Select((item, index) => (item, index)))
        {
            <div class="left@(nums[curr.index])">@curr.item</div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        @foreach (var curr in rights.Select((item, index) => (item, index)))
        {
            <div class="right@(nums[curr.index])">@curr.item</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code above dividing the left Items and right Items seems to be incorrect

```
var allleftItems = ctx.Customers.Take(5);
var allRightItems = ctx.Customers.Skip(Math.Max(0, ctx.Customers.Count() - 2));
```

Instead you could do something like below

```
var allleftItems = ctx.Customers.Take(5);
var allRightItems = ctx.Customers.Skip(5).TakeLast(5);
```

Comment: Thanks ive made that change but the other part is the primary issue